# Newly Assembled Custom PC Suddenly Shuts Off (During Gaming)

Tags: shutdown, gaming

Here are my system specs:

- Intel Core i7 4930K
- GIGABYTE GA-X79-UP4 Motherboard
- G.SKILL Sniper Series 16GB DDR3 2133 (PC3 17000)
- EVGA 03G-P4-2884-KR GeForce GTX 780 Ti Superclocked 3GB
- Seagate Hybrid Drive ST1000DX001 1TB
- RAIDMAX RX-1000AE 1000W

The technical breakdown is:

---

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 3/27/2014, 10:01:08
       Machine name: KRAKEN
   Operating System: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_gdr.131030-1505)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
       System Model: To be filled by O.E.M.
               BIOS: F5
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4930K CPU @ 3.40GHz (12 CPUs), ~3.7GHz
             Memory: 16384MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 16300MB RAM
          Page File: 3163MB used, 16081MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.03.9600.16384 64bit Unicode

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780 Ti
       Manufacturer: EVGA
          Chip type: GeForce GTX 780 Ti
           DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_100A&SUBSYS_28843842&REV_A1
     Display Memory: 11114 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 2963 MB
      Shared Memory: 8150 MB
       Current Mode: 2560 x 1440 (32 bit) (59Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: Acer K272HUL
         Monitor Id: ACR03DD
        Native Mode: 2560 x 1440(p) (59.951Hz)
        Output Type: DVI
        Driver Name: nvd3dumx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvd3dum,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um
Driver File Version: 9.18.0013.3523 (English)
     Driver Version: 9.18.13.3523
        DDI Version: 11
     Feature Levels: 11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.3
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
           Miracast: Not Supported
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Supported
     Power P-states: Not Supported
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 3/4/2014 08:35:23, 17755424 bytes
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes

-------------
Sound Devices
-------------
            Description: Realtek Digital Output (Realtek High Definition Audio)
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
 Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_1458A002&REV_1003
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.7037 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: Yes
```

I have the latest drivers I can find for all of the parts that need drivers. Basically I can surf the web, watch Netflix and do other lightweight things without any issues. Then when I start up a game (Diablo III for example) the game runs smooth with high settings. After about 5 minutes of gaming, the computer unexpectedly shuts off.

I got some help yesterday. He suggested testing the hard drives SMART tests, along with doing a memtest. I did those and they all passed. I should also note, nothing overheated during gaming, so heat isn't the issue. I already tracked the heat and its well below the dangerous shut off level. I also got a benchmark tool from EVGA and pushed my GPU and CPU to their limits. It didn't crashed during that. It only seems to crash during games, so my thinking is it:

Looking through the event log I get this critical error:

```
    Level       Date and Time           Source          Event ID    Task Category
    Critical    3/27/2014 9:55:17 AM    Kernel-Power    41          (63)

The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.
```

This computer is less than 24 hours old. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure the reason somebody would suggest the problem would have anything to do with your HDD.  **The event log is crystal clear you are having a power problem.**  When this happens the computer shuts off, there is no BSOD generated, its simply shuts off?

Comment: Do you have a minidump.dmp file located in: c:\windows\minidump\ Or does it just shutdown without seeing a blue screen of death? I know you said that you "stress" tested your system by using the EVGA to the limits but it almost seems like it could be shutting down because of thermal temps on the video card.

Comment: It just completely powers off. No blue screen :( the only thing windows records is that event log I posted at the bottom of my post.

Comment: No BSOD, simple shot off! I thought it could be power too, but I checked all the cords and power plugins and its all snug in there. When I did my benchmark/stress test, I was using max power from a CPU/GPU standpoint. I still had watts to spare.

Comment: Dang, does it happen ONLY when you start a fairly intense game, or randomly?

Comment: Only during games thus far :/ I even did the Bioshock Infinite Benchmark and it worked! But Bioshock Infinite the game crashed the computer in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Do you have the latest BIOS flashed to your motherboard?
[BIOS](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4288#bios)

Comment: No :/ always been to scared to do it! How does one go about doing it?

Comment: First, download the files from [here](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/BIOS/mb_bios_ga-x79-up4_f4.zip) then view the documentation [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/webpage/20/HowToReflashBIOS.html) NOTE: After reading the WARNINGS from their documentation page it will scare you even more! LOL.

`If you determine to flash BIOS, you are taking a personal risk of BIOS flash failure.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ran Memtest86+ for any less than 48 hours you didn't run it long enough to fully test/burn in new RAM.

Take all but one stick of RAM out, try it, if it fails, switch RAM sticks and try again if it still fails, it's probably not RAM or the timings.

Try a known-good power supply (since it seems like a power problem), and then try a known good video adapter - either of those actions fix it? If yes, replace that part.

New parts out of the box fail, often (especially in comparison to parts that work for months and then just up and die).

"But I don't have extra parts to try with!?" - Welcome to PC building and repair, either have spares to test with, or pay to get it built and tested for you. :)

Comment: :P Thanks! Any way to get Memtest86+ to run for longer? It ran for an hour but then it shut off and the computer restarted it. I was being boring and watching the entire test and it never had any issues pop up on the counter thing. I might have a PSU beefy enough to handle my build, I'll test that after Memtest. Thanks :)

Comment: You need to test RAM for MANY HOURS uninterrupted, and Memetest86+ should run indefinitely (until you stop it). If it's shutting down or rebooting at some point during running Memtest86+, then you have faulty hardware.    If you still think it's RAM, then take all but one stick of RAM out, run Memtest for a day, if good, do next stick for a day, repeat.  But random power-offs as the only/primary symptom are usually power supply or motherboard related.

Comment: Ahhh okay, would that faulty hardware that causes it to reboot in the middle of the test be the RAM most likely?

Comment: IME, nope, not usually. :)  Usually when RAM fails during a Memtest, Memtest86+ catches it and shows you it failed.  Not always though, and it _could be_ the cause -- that's way it's good to test one stick at a time (checking for faulty sticks), and then in pairs (checking for mismatched timings) before ruling them out.  Really though, try a new PSU first, WAY less time-consuming. :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm at work right now, so I'll be sure to do it when I get home :)

Comment: It was the power supply. Ordered a new one and sending the bad one back! Thanks :)